# タッチした座標が弧に含まれるかの判定

Tags: android, java

Android Studioにて、以下のコードからなる図形に対して、 
画面をタッチした時に、その座標が、赤もしくは緑の弧に含まれるかの判定をしたいのですが、 
方法がわからずにいます。

タッチイベントで座標を取得し、座標データを利用する方法がよいのか、 
または、全く違う方法があるのか・・・・ 
よい方法があれば、ご教示をお願い致します。

```
public class Circle extends View{

    public Circle(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        Paint paint1 = new Paint();
        paint1.setColor(Color.argb(255, 255, 0, 0));//red
        Paint paint2 = new Paint();
        paint2.setColor(Color.argb(255,0,255,0));//green

        RectF oval1 = new RectF(50.0f, 50.0f, 400.0f, 400.0f);
        RectF oval2 = new RectF(50.0f, 50.0f, 400.0f, 400.0f);

        canvas.drawArc(oval1, 0, 80, true, paint1);
        canvas.drawArc(oval2, 150, 60, true, paint2);

        paint1.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint2.setAntiAlias(true);

    }
}
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: https://teratail.com/questions/40294 マルチポスト

Comment: teratailでは解決してるみたいです。よく回答を見てないのですが、自己回答するか、回答を承認するかしてください。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

タッチした座標が円弧に含まれるかどうかは、2つの情報があれば分かります。

- 中心座標からの距離
- 中心座標からの角度

距離は三平方の定理で分かります。距離が円の半径より大きければ、円弧の外側です。

角度は逆正接で求められます。`atan2()`というベクトルから角度を求める方法がありますので、これで求めた角度を度数法に変換すればよいです。それぞれの円弧の始点と終点の角度の範囲内かどうかを判定します。

プログラミング的なトピックとしては、数学の座標系では中心が始点 `(0,0)` で第一象限は右上ですが、`View` の座標系では左上が始点 `(0,0)` かつ、y軸が逆転しているという点に注意する必要があります。

また、`Canvas#drawArc()`で指定する角度は、時計の3時の方向が0度になるため、取得した角度を判定するときには、時計回りに90度回転させる必要があります。

例えば、タッチされた場合に色を変える場合は以下のようなコードになります。（簡単のために横幅 500px、縦幅 500px の `View` としています）

```
public class Circle extends View {

    private Paint paint = new Paint();
    private RectF rect = new RectF();

    private boolean inGreen = false;
    private boolean inRed = false;

    public Circle(Context context) {
        super(context);
        initialize();
    }

    public Circle(Context context, AttributeSet attribute) {
        super(context, attribute);
        initialize();
    }

    private void initialize() {
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        rect.set(50.f, 50.f, 400.f, 400.f);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        int width = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(500, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
        int height = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(500, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
        setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        paint.setColor(inRed ? Color.WHITE : Color.RED);
        canvas.drawArc(rect, 0, 80, true, paint);

        paint.setColor(inGreen ? Color.WHITE : Color.GREEN);
        canvas.drawArc(rect, 150, 60, true, paint);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        float x = event.getX() - 250.f;
        float y = 250.f - event.getY();
        float distance = (float) Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
        if (distance > 200) {
            inGreen = false;
            inRed = false;
        } else {
            int angle = (int) Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(x, y));
            angle = angle > 0 ? angle : angle + 360;
            inRed = angle >= 90 && angle <= 170;
            inGreen = angle >= 240 && angle <= 300;
        }
        invalidate();
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: 回答頂きありがとうございます。

Comment: とても丁寧に解説、また、コードまで記載頂き感謝致します。